# Work done by the drift term of Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process

Tags: work, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider a particle obeying [the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process):
$$
dx_{t}=\theta (\mu -x_{t})\,dt+\sigma \,dW_{t},
$$
where $x_t$ is the position of the particle at time $t$, $W_t$ denotes the Wiener process and $\theta, \mu, \sigma$ are scalar parameters.

Because the particle stochastically moves close to $\mu$, I believe that it is required to consume energy provided by some external source.

My question is how much external energy is consumed during $0 < t < T$ or $0 < t < \infty$ in order to drive this process.

Both analytical solution and a way of numerical method are welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't $\langle E\rangle\sim\langle (\mathrm dx/\mathrm dt)^2\rangle$ be what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't $\langle (dx/dt)^2 \rangle$ include the effect of the Wiener process in addition to the drift term? @KyleKanos

Comment: Well if you want to ignore the stochastic term, it's not much different from a spring, no?